# creating an image changes the network adapter name

Tags: azure, networking, virtual-machine

I have a VM which have a network adapter called 'Ethernet'.

When I create an image from this VM, any VM that I create from that image have only one network adapter named 'Ethernet 2'.

How can I force it have the same network adapter name?

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expected behavior. Network adapter would also change if your VM is healed (i.e. the underlying hardware fails and your image is re-instantiated on a new one). This will also happen if you scale the VM (change the VM size). Changing the name of the network adapter also would happen sometimes when you shutdown the VM (from the portal, which would also de-allocate resources).

Even if the above mentioned limitations are fixed (today, or in the future). I would not rely on using specific name for the adapter in my application.

Even with the recently added feature to have multiple NICs, [as described here](http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/10/30/multiple-vm-nics-and-network-virtual-appliances-in-azure/), you cannot influence the name of the NIC which the OS uses:

> The interface name must be unique for the VM, but does not represent
>   the names of the NICs inside the VM.

It is important to know that the settings for the NIC you dictate from your Virtual Network setup (DNS, IP Address, Subnet Mask) are guaranteed to be taken by your VM. So why the need for specific network adapter name. Also, keep in mind that you should never manually change the network settings inside an Azure VM.